# How to get the 'execution count' of the most recent execution in IPython or a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython

IPython and Jupyter notebooks keep track of an 'execution count'. This is e.g. shown in the prompts for input and output: `In[...]` and `Out[...]`.

How can you get the latest execution count programmatically?

The variable `Out` cannot be used for this:

- `Out` is a dictionary, with execution counts as keys, but only for those cells that yielded a result; note that not all (cell) executions need to yield a result (e.g. `print(...)`).

The variable `In` *seems* to be usable:

- `In` is a list of all inputs; it *seems* that `In[0]` is always primed with an empty string, so that you can use the 1-based execution count as index.

However, when using `len(In) - 1`, in your code, you need to take into account that the execution count *seems* to be updated before execution of that new code.  So, actually, it *seems* you need to use `len(In) - 2` for the execution count of the most recent *already completed* execution.

Questions:

- Is there a better way to get the current execution count?
- Can you rely on the above observations (the '*seems*')?

Comment: To a point, I think you are safe assuming your observations hold. The input caching system that you are referencing is fairly well established and [documented](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/reference.html#input-caching-system). You could perhaps also use `%hist -n` in your efforts to get the current execution count.

Comment: @Wayne: I would like to have the execution count inside my Python code. Maybe the IPython API offers a way. I know you can have it execute magic commands (something like `IPython.get_ipython().run_line_magic(...)`), but that feels like a very roundabout way. But this did lead to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

After more digging, I found the (surprisingly simple) answer:

```py
from IPython import get_ipython

ipython = get_ipython()

... ipython.execution_count ...
```

This does not show up in the IPython documentation, though could (should?) have been mentioned here: https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html (I guess attributes are not documented). Here you do find `run_line_magic` (which was mentioned in a comment to my question).

The way I found this attribute is by defining `ipython` as above and then doing code completion (TAB) on `ipython.` (but it does not have documentation).

```
help(ipython)
```

gives you documentation about `InteractiveShell`, and it does mention `execution_count` (though it does not confirm its purpose):

```
 |  execution_count
 |      An int trait.
```

Comment: Two things:

a) You could also have done `dir(ipython)` after you define `ipython` the way you did. It lists the available functions & attributes there. b) I think with the documentation, you are seeing a number of issues. There is limited community resources. Also, IPython & Jupyter have only [recently diverged](https://ipython.org/#jupyter-and-the-future-of-ipython). For example, in [the IPython documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/development/execution.html), `execute_request` redirects  to Jupyter documentation that features `execution_count`.